# Filter index by condition into a new list using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe let's call it **df1**:

```
              GOOG    AAPL     XOM     IBM        Cash  zero
2011-01-10     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     -19.900     4
2011-01-11     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0       0.000     5
2011-01-12     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0       0.000     5
2011-01-13     0.0 -1500.0     0.0  4000.0  -67392.400     2
```

The last column of it represents how many of the columns contain value of zero. 
**I want to create a new data frame** that contains the dates in which colum zero is **one**less than 5; meaning searches for every row with 4 in column zero.

This snippet of code has the intention of achieving this;

```
total_columns =trades['zero'].max()-1
trades_impact = trades.index.where(trades['zero'] == total_columns)
```

This is what I'm getting;

```
DatetimeIndex(['NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT',
           'NaT',
           ...
           'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT',
           'NaT'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=245, freq=None)
```

The output that I expect is:

```
>>>trades_impact
2011-01-10    
2011-01-11     
2011-01-12     
2011-01-13
```

trades_impact will be a new data frame.

Any help will be more than welcome.

Comment: `df.index[df.zero == 4].tolist()`

Comment: Is printing this:[Timestamp('2011-01-10 00:00:00')]

Comment: I would have expected the same output as in df1 in terms of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing on `df.index`, and then convert to a string.

```
df.index[df.zero == 4].astype(str).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I don't think you want the [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method, since it returns an object that is the same shape as self (the object to which it is applied). The values of the new object are chosen from either self (if the condition is `True`) or from the `other` object (second argument), if the condition is `False`. You don't specify the other object, so it defaults to `NaN`.

The result you are getting is a Series of the same length as `index` with a value of `NaT` for every location where `trades['zero'] == total_columns` is `False`.

Instead, I think you will get the result you want if you use the indexing function directly:

```
trades_impact = trades.index[trades['zero'] == total_columns]
```